# Add a new Key-Value to an existing HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, treeset

I'm trying to add a new Key/Value to an existing HashMap (bandMap) where the second argument in my test() method must be of a Collection type. 
As I'm still very new to Java so any help with an explanation would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*; 
public class Car
{
private Map<String, Set<String>> carMap = new HashMap<>(); //b
Set<String> model = new TreeSet<>();
/**
* Constructor for a Band object
*/
public void make()//b
{
Map<String, Set<String>> carMap = new HashMap<>();
}

/**
* Populate some sample data
*/
public void populate() //b
{

  model.add("Fiesta");
  model.add("Cougar");
  model.add("Transit");
  carMap.put("Ford", model);

  model = new TreeSet<>();
  model.add("Astra");
  model.add("Calibra");
  carMap.put("Vauxhall", model);

  model = new TreeSet<>();
  model.add("206");
  model.add("106");
  carMap.put("Peugeot", model);

 }

/**
* I need a method to add a new key - value pair
*/   

public void test(String makeName, Set<String> aModel)
{
 //Code to add new Key/Value to the exisiting HashMap (carMap)
}
}
```

Comment: A look at [`HashMap`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) might help. A note on your question: not every `Collection` is a `Set`.

Comment: Your `make()` method is no constructor - it only creates a *local*  variable named `carMap` that is immediately out of scope at the end of the method. It does not modify the `carMap`-field in `Car`. That said, the code will not compile as listed here, because all methods need to be contained in classes in java.

Comment: I've edited the sample code so that it now compiles. I will look at the constructor.

Comment: Read the documentation - that will help you

Comment: Regarding the constructor just write `public Car() { .. }`

Comment: Thank you guys but after reading the documentation there doesn't appear to be anything obvious on how to answer my question. Do I need to create a copy of the existing map and then add the new one onto it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the `carMap` as a class variable. And in your `test()` method (I renamed it `addModel`) simply use the put method as you do it in the populate method.

```
public class Car {

    private Map<String, Set<String>> carMap = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Populate some sample data
     */
    public void populate() {

        Set<String> model = new TreeSet<>();
        model.add("Fiesta");
        model.add("Cougar");
        model.add("Transit");
        carMap.put("Ford", model);

        model = new TreeSet<>();
        model.add("Astra");
        model.add("Calibra");
        carMap.put("Vauxhall", model);

        model = new TreeSet<>();
        model.add("206");
        model.add("106");
        carMap.put("Peugeot", model);

    }

    public void addModel(String makeName, Set<String> aModel) {
        carMap.put(makeName, aModel);
    }

    public Map<String, Set<String>> getCarMap() {
        return carMap;
    }
}
```

Then use it this way

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Car car = new Car();
    car.populate();
    car.addModel("AnotherBrand", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b")));
    System.out.println(car.getCarMap());

}
```

This outputs the following Map

```
{
    Vauxhall=[Astra, Calibra], 
    Ford=[Cougar, Fiesta, Transit], 
    AnotherBrand=[a, b], 
    Peugeot=[106, 206]
}
```